# Set visibility of the group of controls in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, visibility

I have 2 logical groups of controls (textboxes,buttons, etc), and I'd like to have an opportunity to change their visibility: for example when the program loads the first group is visible, and after clicking on some button it becomes collapsed and the other group becomes visible. What's the best way to implement this kind of behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a functionality similar to a TabPanel. You might actually use one and change the style so it doesn't look like a TabPanel but more like a Navigation bar.

Otherwise all would have to implement the functionality by yourself of showing and hiding your areas.

Maybe you should also take a look at the navigation framework: http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/The-Silverlight-3-Navigation-Framework.aspx ... It adds the functionality that view changes are tracked in the URL so that users can also use back/forward buttons in their browsers when navigating through your page.